# Ghidra python - get program base address

Tags: elf, ghidra

What is the way to get the program base address in `Ghidra`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`currentProgram.getImageBase()`](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/model/listing/Program.html#getImageBase()) to obtain the base address. This returns an `Address` object.

#### Example

```
>>> currentProgram.getImageBase()
00400000

>>> type(currentProgram.getImageBase())
<type 'ghidra.program.model.address.GenericAddress'>

>>> currentProgram.getImageBase().getOffset()
4194304L

>>> hex(currentProgram.getImageBase().getOffset())
'0x400000L'
```